# extract environmental value from points predicted from maxent

Tags: r-raster, maxent

I have used maxent to predict species distribution model of interested species.
I would like to extract point (coordinate) with high confidence predicted from maxent (eg >0.8), and use these point to extract their detail environmental factors using raster and Worldclim database.
However, I don't know how can I quickly extract points with high confidence.
Do any experts know ways to do this?

Comment: Can you share some more information on your data/code? For more info see [How to make a great R reproducible example?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example)

Comment: I have never used `maxent` or conducted species distribution modeling before. But it sounds like you want to first determine which points have high confidence and then extract values from raster layers based on those points. It would be great if you can share a reproducible example of the `maxent` output and some raster layers.